# Error while trying to add days to a date with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I wrote the following script to add days to a given date:

```
$("#rec_days").change(function(){                    
    var start_date = new Date($("#start_date").attr('value'));                                    
    var rec_days = $("#rec_days").attr('value');
    var end_date = new Date(start_date).setDate(start_date.getDate() + rec_days); 
    $("#end_date").val(end_date.getFullYear() + '-' + end_date.getMonth() + '-' . end_date.getDate());                                    
});
```

Console logs the following error: "TypeError: end_date.getFullYear is not a function".

The input date is YYYY-MM-DD and I would like for the output date to be in the same format.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$("#rec_days").change(function(){                    
    var start_date = new Date($("#start_date").val());                                    
    var rec_days = parseInt($("#rec_days").val());
    var end_date = new Date(start_date);
    end_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() + rec_days); 
    $("#end_date").val(end_date.getFullYear() + '-' + (end_date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + end_date.getDate());                                    
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmann/37FGC/)

Comment: Tried it, returns `NaN-NaN-NaN`.

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else. The value of rec_days has to be a number, start_date has to be date. Try debugging those values, look at my fiddle to see correct usage.

Answer (score 0):

`
Try this

```
var end_date = new Date(start_date);
end_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() + parseInt(rec_days)); //the problem was because of this line. the addition was not proper. use parseInt to convert to int.

$("#end_date").val(end_date.getFullYear() + '-' + (end_date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + end_date.getDate());
```